# WordPress CSS changing preset for one page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Currently I'm helping about with a WordPress site and we have a fixed CSS (I guess that's the case in every WordPress Page) and its set that is "transforms" all letters into Uppercase.

Well I'm supposed to post one article where that shouldn't be the case.

I know that I can access the specific CSS Settings of one Page over the CSS Button, but honestly I don't know what to type to change the preset for this particular page.

Comment: Check your body tag. There may be helpful classes. Something like "post-id-" will get you that specific page. Then you can use that to target that specific page.

Comment: You can right-click on a sample of text in your website and choose "Inspect Element" in most browsers. This will help you narrow down which style is responsible for introducing that rendering rule.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of in the Visual editor, go to the Text editor. At the very top of the article, do this:

```
<div style="text-transform: none;">
```

And at the end of the article, do:

```
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

But im afraid it didn't work :(

Comment: Is the original rule tagged with !important or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can add css code below and put it on the Additional CSS Customizer (WP 4.7 or higher) or put into style.css file

```
.page-id-24 {
    text-transform: none; /* you may need to use 'none !important' */
}
```

Please note that you can use `.page-id-{pageid}` for page and `.post-id-{postid}` for post. For certain element such as `p`, `h1` and etc you can use `.page-id-{pageid} {html tag}`.

Cheers!